# Using ddply across numerous variables when calculating descriptive statistics

Tags: r, statistics, dplyr, plyr

Here's my data. It shows the amount of fish I found at three different sites.

```
Selidor.Bay Enlades.Bay Cumphrey.Bay
1      39         29        187
2      70        370         50
3      13         44         52
4       0         65         20
5      43        110        220
6       0         30        266
```

What I would like to do is create a script to calculate basic statistics for each site.

If I re-arrange the data by stacking it. I.e :

```
values  site
1   29  Selidor.Bay
2   370 Selidor.Bay
3   44  Selidor.Bay
4   65  Enlades.Bay
```

I'm able to use the following:

```
data <- ddply(df, c("site"), summarise,
                N    = length(values),
                mean = mean(values),
                sd   = sd(values),
                se   = sd / sqrt(N),
                sum = sum(values)
)
data.
```

My question is how can I use the script without having to stack my dataframe?

Thanks.

Comment: Try `library(dplyr); summarise_each(df, funs(N = n(), mean, sd, sum))`

Comment: It's simpler if you're willing to depart from `ddply` (mentioned in your title), as shown in docendo's comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slight variation on @docendodiscimus' comment:

```
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)

DF %>% 
  melt(variable.name="site") %>% 
  group_by(site) %>%
  summarise_each(funs( n(), mean, sd, se=sd(.)/sqrt(n()), sum ), value)

#           site n  mean        sd       se sum
# 1  Selidor.Bay 6  27.5  27.93385 11.40395 165
# 2  Enlades.Bay 6 108.0 131.84688 53.82626 648
# 3 Cumphrey.Bay 6 132.5 104.29909 42.57992 795
```

`melt` does what the OP referred to as "stacking" the data.frame. There is likely some analogous function in the `tidyr` package.